# TFS2010 -Work item Search Popup is not Working

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

TFS2010- Work item Search Popup control is not working ,no error message is showing .Please share your valueable comments on it .Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931509 .Solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Despite work items not depend on the Data warehouse, but I think the problem that appears of the Data warehouse is critical because wrong date, and this can lead to error in everywhere; so the server is out dated and you need to adjust the time of the server instead of (**1900**)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But actual my problem is different, I will explain. you can see a red color box on top right of the attached image. If we provide a tfs task id there and click on go button normally there should be a pop up window will come with details of the corresponding id. but for some users it is not coming and also they are not getting new work item and its corresponding links. please share your ideas on it  .Thanks a lot